# CustomValidity for input type email

Tags: validation, email

I managed to set a custom validity function for my input and textarea tags, since I'm working with a german browser, but wanted to display the warning in english.

Now - if I set the input type to "email", it shows the aforementioned customized warning,
but I want a different one only for the type "email"...

Here's my code so far:

```
var elements = document.getElementsById("email");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("You've entered an invalid email adress");
        }
    };
    elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    };
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It is `getElementById`, in order to return one element with the specified id.

Comment: thanks, but it still shows the customized warning which I set for all input fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code posted you have used`getElementById`, which returns only one element with the specified id.

If you replace it with `var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=email]");` everything will work fine.

**example**

http://jsfiddle.net/X8zHP/

**js**

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=email]");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("You've entered an invalid email adress");
        }
    };
    elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    };
}
```

**html**

```
<form action="#" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```